# Custom Reinforcement Learning Environment with Neural Network

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm currently working on a reinforcement learning project.
In this project the dynamics of the environment is modeled with a neural network surrogate model.
I would like to build a custom environment including this neural network which runs on a GPU.
Therefor the environment should accept and return tensors (pytorch). This would enable to run the whole training process on the GPU without switching between CPU & GPU (numpy arrays & pytorch tensors).

So far I know about openai gymnasium environments, which work with numpy arrays.
Is there any framework for training RL and building environments for multi-process on GPU?
I'm thankful for any opinion, hint or experience.
Thanks

Comment: maybe [brax](https://github.com/google/brax) / [evojax](https://github.com/google/evojax) or [powder](https://kvfrans.com/static/powder/)